# Is this proof of $\pi$’s uniformity correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, pi

I wanted to know if the digits of $\pi$ are truly uniform, so I attempted a proof of it as a homework question. Can you guys let me know if it is right?

—————-

Let $\Pi$ represent the ordered set of $\pi$'s digits such that \begin{align*} \Pi &= \{\{0, 0, \cdots, 0\}, \{1, 1, \cdots, 1\}, \cdots, \{9, 9, \cdots, 9\}\} \\
&= \{S_0, S_1, \cdots, S_9 \},
\end{align*}
where $S_l$ represents the set of digits whose values are all equal to $l$. Next, let $n_{l}$ represent the cardinality of subset $S_{l}$ such that  $$n_l = \sum_{i=1}^{|\Pi| = \infty}{\Delta_{li}},$$ where  $$\Delta_{li} =  \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1 & \mbox{if} \  \mathcal{D}_{i} = l  \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ for the $i^{th}$ digit $\mathcal{D}_{i}$.  If $ 0 < p_{l} \leq 1$ represents the fixed probability that any digit $\mathcal{D}$ is equal to $l$,  then $$\Delta_{i} \sim \mathrm{Bernouli}\left(p = p_{l}\right),$$ and consequently $$n_{l} \sim \mathrm{Binomial}\left(n = \infty, p = p_{l}\right),$$ which expresses $n_{l}$ as a function of independent and identically distributed events $\Delta_{1}, \Delta_{2}, \cdots, \Delta_{i}, \cdots, \Delta_{\infty}.$ Since \begin{align*} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{p_{l}} &= \infty \times p_{l} \\
&= \infty, \end{align*} it follows from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma that $$\Pr\left(n_{l} = \infty \right) =1$$ as long as $p_{l} > 0$. And since $$ \bigcup_{l=1}^{9}S_{l} = \Pi$$ and $$\Pr\left(n_{0} = n_{1} = \cdots = n_{9}\right) = 1,$$ the probability that $D_{i} = l$ is equal for all $l$.
————————-

I apologize in advance if the proof looks sloppy. I didn’t know it was an open question, I just thought it was from homework. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing in this answer about the number $\pi$.  And in what way did you think this is a homework problem?

Comment: @KCd, sorry, I don’t understand what you mean in the first sentence. And for the homework problem, I was learning about large sample theory and wanted to test my knowledge of the first chapter of the book. I chose this question because I figured it was already answered before

Comment: You seem to be arguing that in *any* real number (or maybe in any irrational number) the digits are equally distributed, but this is clearly false.

Comment: @lulu I did make an assumption that the probability that a digit occurs is strictly non-zero, which is violated if there is a finite number of a particular digit in an infinite sequence, so a bit of circular logic. But I don’t think this is for any real number, just those whose digits have nonzero chances of occurinh

Comment: But this is clearly false.  The rational number $.\overline {0112223333444445555556666667777777888888888899999999999}$ each digit occurs with a different probability (barring typos, each digit $d$ occurs $d+1$ times in the block).  For $\pi$ it is not even known if each digit occurs infinitely often.

Comment: You can't claim some probability argument applies to a specific real number without using some actual property of that number.  There is nothing at all in the *reasoning* of your post that makes it applicable to $\pi$. You wrote in another comment that you made "an assumption that the probability that a digit occurs is strictly non-zero" but you gave no rationale for why this is true about $\pi$ or any other specific number.

Comment: @lulu This is a really good point, thank you! I was thinking that in this case, the probability of say 0 occurring wouldn’t be nonzero as there’s only a finite number of 0s that truly occur, so summing them across infinity wouldn’t be true.

Comment: Borel proved almost every real number in $[0,1]$ has each digit in its base $b$ expansion occur in the expansion with equal probability $1/b$ (for bases $b = 2, 3, 4, \ldots$).  Look up "normal number".  There can be a *huge* gap between showing by probabilistic reasoning that most numbers have a property and showing that a *specific* number has that property.  As another example, it is easy to show that a "random" real number is transcendental ($\mathbf R$ is uncountable and algebraic numbers are countable), but it is *very hard* to show $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: @KCd I didn’t include the rational here, I’m sorry about that! It was based off of simulation studies that tested the probability that the proportion of each digit was zero. The hypothesis tests were significant which gave some reasoning behind assuming that the probability was strictly non zero.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments! :D I really appreciate this feedback. I know it’s an open question but now I’m fueled to read all I can about normal numbers :)

Comment: Bernoulli has two $l$s

Answer (score 1):

The premise that $0, \ldots, 9$ even have a definite probability of appearing among the digits of $\pi$ is an open problem, let alone that such probabilities are related to Bernoulli distributions.  So there is no proof here, just some heuristic reasoning.

That you don't make an actual connection to the number $\pi$ is another gap, but even without that we can't say that your argument applies to any specific real number.  Borel proved in $1909$ that for almost all numbers in $[0,1]$, each base $b$ digit appears with frequency $1/b$, for every base $b \geq 2$. That is, the set of such numbers in $[0,1]$ has measure $1$.  Note that part of his proof involves showing the digit frequencies even exist at all; their existence is not an assumption. That a set in $[0,1]$ has measure $1$ does not mean we can easily give examples of numbers in that set: to this day, no specific number that anyone actually cares about has been proved to be normal.